# How can I make word blocks of text that go inside of <textarea>s?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

In the website I am working on, I need there to be a `<textarea>` where the user can write a description, and add user-defined variables as shown below:[image: screenshot of what I just described]

When one of the buttons is clicked, it adds the corresponding text to the `<textarea>` above. Then, in the JS, I use the replaceAll() method to substitute the variables added with their corresponding values.

This works and all, but I would want to do is go for something that looks like this:
[image: variables acting like blocks instead of text]

So I still want the block of text to function the same as before, but it would be sort of like one character, where if you hit the backspace on it it would delete the whole block. Is there a way I can go about doing this (using Vanilla JS)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what have you tried so far? what is not working by including the text with a `variable` and using `textarea.innerHTML += variable;`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't render HTML in a textarea. What you'll need is a content editable DIV – here is some rough HTML & CSS.

```html
<div contenteditable="true" >
  Hi, My Name Is BusinessName
</div>
```